# How to rewrite running jar file

Tags: java, command, line

I need to rewrite jar file when update is coming. To rewtite it, I do following:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe",
            "/c",
            "timeout 10",
            "&&",
            "move",
            "/Y",
            file.toAbsolutePath().toString(),
            System.getProperty("user.dir")
);
```

Run command line, sleep 10 secinds and move dowload file. When command line is sleeping I close program. But when I use "&&" it doesn't work, but when I use "&" it works but doesn't sleep.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this:

```
File fileDestination = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + file.getName());
file.renameTo(fileDestination);
```

Is easier if you avoid using OS dependent commands.

Sfc